# TypeError:object is not callable

Tags: python, callable

My Python script is:

```
from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from caeModules import *
from odbAccess import *
from driverUtils import executeOnCaeStartup
executeOnCaeStartup()
openMdb(pathName='3d-test.cae')
p = mdb.models['Model-1'].parts['beam']
mdb.models['Model-1'].materials['cdp'].concreteDamagedPlasticity(table=((15.00,0.1,1.16,0.6777,0.000001), ))
```

and my error is:

```
FileAbaqus.py",line23,in <module>
  mdb.models['Model-1'].materials['cdp'].concreteDamagedPlasticity(table=((15.00,0.1,1.16,0.6777,0.000001), )) 
TypeError:object is not callable
```

Comment: i'm confused.help me please.

Comment: `concreteDamagedPlasticity` is not a function. I wasn't able to find any of your modules by a quick google search, so I guess these are defined by yourself. Look up the code where `concreteDamagedPlasticity` is defined.

Comment: hi dear hegedus.concreteDamagedPlasticity is a material model in abaqus software and i need to run my abaqus model with this material model by python script.

Comment: this model have a five parameter and i try to define it's within script.but deal with this error